# How to stop people from entering a certain charaters in a row in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

My problem is I want to block people from putting certain names. Currently I was putting an if statement. The thing is they can simply change the lowercase letter to A Upper-case letter and then they'd be able to use the name But with an Uppercase B. How can I make it so they can't use the same characters in a row, So it wouldn't matter if they made it a lowercase b or an Uppercase B

```
Private Sub GhostButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GhostButton1.Click

    Try
        DownloadResponse = GetResponse.DownloadString("http://Example.com/target=" & GhostTextBox1.Text)
        FormatResponse = DownloadResponse.Split(New Char() {ControlChars.Lf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        RichTextBox1.Text = FormatResponse(0)
        If GhostTextBox1.Text = "buster3636" Then RichTextBox1.Text = "You can not put this name"
```

Comment: there is probably a string_to_lower case function that will help you out so the case of the entry won't matter

Answer (score 2):

Use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` in [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx)

```
If GhostTextBox1.Text.Equals("buster3636", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
    RichTextBox1.Text = "You can not put this name"
End If
```

If one or both could also be `Nothing` which could cause a `NullReferenceException` i would prefer:

```
StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(GhostTextBox1.Text, "buster3636")
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use ToLower(...):

```
If GhostTextBox1.Text.ToLower() = "buster3636" ...
```

Comment: fair point, but in a simple English application ToLower(..) would suffice.

Comment: Why should i use code which could fail later when it's also less efficient? If you want to use this trick anyway i would prefer `ToUpperInvariant`.